# Sum of the divisor function over integers with restricted prime factors

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $a,q$ be co-prime integers and let $P(a,q)$ denote the set of primes congruent to $a$ modulo $q$. Is it known whether one can give an asymptotic formula for the expression

$$\displaystyle \sum_{\substack{n \leq x \\ p | n \Rightarrow p \in P(a,q)}} d(n),$$
where $d(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure.  The generating function for the sum you want is the Dirichlet series 
$$ 
\sum_{\substack{ n=1\\p|n \implies p\equiv a\pmod q}}^{\infty} \frac{d(n)}{n^s} = \prod_{p\equiv a\pmod q} \Big(1- \frac{1}{p^s}\Big)^{-2}.
$$ 
Using Dirichlet characters to isolate primes in progressions, you can express this as 
$$ 
\zeta(s)^{2/\phi(q)} \prod_{\chi \neq \chi_0 \pmod q} L(s,\chi)^{\overline{\chi(a)}/\phi(q)} G(s), 
$$ 
for a suitable Euler product $G$ converging absolutely to the right of $1/2$.  Now use the Selberg-Delange method (see e.g. Tenenbaum's book).  The asymptotic will be of the type 
$$ 
\sim C x(\log x)^{-1+2/\phi(q)}
$$ 
for a suitable constant $C$.

Comment: Can the constant  $ C $ be expressed in terms of  $ a $  and  $ q $?

Comment: Yes, it will be $\prod_{\chi \neq \chi_0 \pmod q} L(1,\chi)^{\overline{\chi(a)}/\phi(q)} G(1)$ in the notation of the answer; $G$ can be explicitly written down easily. Tenenbaum's book has all the details.

Comment: Greg forgot to divide by $\Gamma(2/\phi(q))$, but apart from that the constant is what he wrote.

Comment: I think there is a $2$ missing in the exponent of the $L(s,\chi)$ term.